# Unable to get react-navigation working: `Element type is invalid`

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm unable to get the examples for react-navigation working. I always end up wiht the error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.`

This is using the example from the [intro page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/)

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    return <Text>Hello, Navigation!</Text>;
  }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleApp', () => SimpleApp);
```

I'm building for iOS and running on a device (not the simulator).

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to export HomeScreen class:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
```

replace this with

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
```